# Differences between the `directName` and `directName/` in `.gitignore`

Tags: git, gitignore

Differences between the `directName` and `directName/` in `.gitignore`.

In the `.gitignore` there can edit like this:

```
venv
venv/
```

the `vevn` is a directory.
so what's the differences between them?

Comment: `venv/` will be treated as a folder, but `venv` will be treated a glob pattern relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file.  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`venv/` will basically ignore whole of the directory.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, and it should probably be a comment.

Comment: but the `venv` will ignore the `venv` directory too.